# Suspend camel route for a specific request

Tags: spring-boot, routes, apache-camel

Problem Statement: I have a request(having metadata of multiple files). I have configured the camel route as per the below code.

```
@Override
public void configure() {

String sourceUri = getSourceUri();
String destinationUri = getDestinationUri();

onException(StopRouteException.class)
    .process(new StopRouteProcessor())
    .log("Stop Event processed for req id : " + reqId)
    .end();

onException(Exception.class)
    .process(new RouteExceptionProcessor())
    .onRedelivery(new RouteRedeliveryProcessor())
    .maximumRedeliveries(maxRetries)
    .redeliveryDelay(retryDelay)
    .handled(false)
    .log("Error Occurred while moving file to path : " + destinationUri)
    .end();

from(sourceUri)
    .log("Transferring File from " + sourcePath + " to " + destinationUri)
    .process(new PreMoveProcessor())
    .to(destinationUri)
    .process(new PostMoveProcessor())
    .log("File Upload Success.");
}
```

Somewhere in my microservice, a "Stop" event would have listened. After that, it should stop transferring all files of that particular request.

In PreMoveProcessor, I can poll that stop event and throw the StopRouteException which will stop the transferring of that File. But if there are multiple files in this request then those will be transferred after that.

I need a mechanism to stop transferring files of a particular request. I cannot stop the route as there will be other requests getting processed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are using splitter to split the request's metadata and then sending them to `from(sourceUri)`?

If so splitter has .stopOnException() clause that does what you want. If you are not doing it this way I recommend giving it a try. Something in the way of:

```
split(request.metadata).stopOnException()
     .to(sourceUri)
```

Comment: No, I'm not using a splitter because it will make the file transfer asynchronous. I have to transfer all files of a particular request in a synchronous way.

Comment: The splitter is not asynchronous by default. if you enable .parallelprocessing(true) then it is. How are you currently processing the metadata and launching the requests?